# Why is WCF Stream response getting corrupted on write to disk?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, streaming, stream

I am wanting to write a WCF web service that can send files over the wire to the client.  So I have one setup that sends a Stream response.  Here is my code on the client:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Picture.jpg";
    if (File.Exists(filename))
        File.Delete(filename);

    StreamServiceClient client = new StreamServiceClient();

    int length = 256;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    FileStream sink = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
    Stream source = client.GetData();
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buffer,0,length))> 0)
    {
        sink.Write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    source.Close();
    sink.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("All done");
}
```

Everything processes fine with no errors or exceptions. The problem is that the .jpg file that is getting transferred is reported as being "corrupted or too large" when I open it.

What am I doing wrong?

On the server side, here is the method that is sending the file.

```
public Stream GetData()
{
    string filename = Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\\Chrysanthemum.jpg";
    FileStream myfile = File.OpenRead(filename);
    return myfile;
}
```

I have the server configured with basicHttp binding with Transfermode.StreamedResponse.

Comment: don't forget to employ a using() clause around the FileStream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is this:

```
while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buffer,0,length))> 0)
{
    sink.Write(buffer,0,length);
}
```

Imagine you're reading the last bit of your file - maybe it's not 256 bytes anymore, but only 10.

You read those last 10 bytes, `bytesRead` will be 10, but on the `sink.Write` operation, you're still using the fixed value `length` (256). So when you read the last block of data, you're writing out a block that might be too large.

You need to change the line for the `sink` to:

```
   sink.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

and then it should work.